# Border applying to the items inside of my grid rather than the grid itself

Tags: html, css

Hey so I'm trying to have black borders in between each tab at the top of my page (shown below), however when I try to add `border-left: ;` it adds it to the text in the cell rather than the cell itself.

I have tried adding:

```
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

but this messes with the text inside as well.

This is where I would want the border to be:
[image]

and this is where I would want the text to be:
[image]

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #70614b;
}

.banner {
  display: grid;
  z-index: 1;
  position: fixed;
  width: auto;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: #d7cdc7;
  grid-template: 100% / 20% repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2px;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.about {
  grid-area: 1 / 2 / span 1 / span 1;
}

.tabs {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>

  <link href="./style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <div class="banner">

    <div class="logo"><img src="./photos/aa logo.png" /></div>
    <div class="about tabs"><a href="">ABOUT</a></div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: you can give some padding to your about class to get expected result.

Answer (score 0):

Without modifying your stylesheet too much, I'd suggest giving your tabs selector the height of its parent and then aligning the text using flex. It should look like this:

```
.tabs {
  font-family: Roboto;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  border-left: 2px black solid;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Hope it helps!